# MVC View with IEnumerable<T> model comes from Linq To Entities - object disposed error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I am getting "Object Disposed" exception because I pass the result of the Linq query as IEnumerable into a view, but the linq runs inside a using block that surrounds the db context. What is the best way to resolve this, preferable avoiding extra boilerplating?

I've got this in the controller, notice the using block that disposes the linq query I think:

HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();

```
 using (var ctx = new MyContext())
 {
    model.StuffList = (from p in ctx.Stuffs orderby p.ModifiedDate descending select p).Take(10);
 }
```

Inside the view I've got:

```
@model IEnumerable<Stuff>
```

It falls over with "Object Disposed" exception when it starts rendering the view. WCS I can create a separate list for the  viewmodel and copy the results but I want to avoid extra boiler plating, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `.ToList()` to your query to materialize it

Comment: It worked. That and changing the bit to @model List<Stuff>. Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ and other Data-Access related frameworks will return you a IEnumerable as a contract. The advantage is, that the data does not need to be fetched at this very moment. LINQ remains in control of how and when it wants to query your data. E.g.: If you only apply a `.Count()` to the enumerable object, linq might only queries the database using a sql count statement.

This behavior leaves it in your responsibility to explicitly fetch the data befor closing any db-context, web-request or wherever your IEnumerable<> comes from.

`.ToList()` comes in handy to force the allocation of the result.